# How do you make a 2d object go through another and detect there was a collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2D snowboard game in which there will be snowballs that you will have to dodge, if you get hit by the snowball it will disappear and subtract the score.

I tried creating two game objects called Player and Ball and the code to detect the collision looks like this.

```
void Update
{
   if (Player.transform.position.x == Ball.transform.position.x)
                        score--;
}
```

I'm not sure if I should create a OnCollisionEnter but i'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: If the game objects have colliders, then OnCollisionEnter event is a good idea.

Comment: How would I do that, When i've tried it just makes the snowball hit the player, I want it to as soon as they overlap the ball will disappear and minus the score

Comment: Triggers are what you want: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders-as-triggers

Answer (score 0):

Use OnTriggerEnter or OnCollisionEnter 
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html